# How to embed a facebook page wall into wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-wall

Is there a way to embed a Facebook page wall into a wordpress website?

I want to have the wall exactly as styled from Facebook, with all actions to Like, Comment and Share but from my website.

Ps: ..and I not looking for a wordpress plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

And look out for "feed".

Comment: thnaks Scorcher, i found this example ...http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall

Got it work but, im trying to get it work within wordpress.  thanks for your help.

Comment: dont worry, solved it. used an iframe. - not sure if this is the right solution though ... but it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a tutorial on how to do it? Or something you can just drop in the code?
I wrote a jquery plugin that will do it for you, http://ironlasso.com/jqueryfacebookwall-plugin/